# Saving the mapping reference in Object in MongoDB TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm using Nest/Mongoose in the project. I want to update an object through the FindByIdAndUpdate or FindOneAndUpdate methods. I'm getting data from a DTO with class-validator. When it comes to the service layer update method I'm using UpdateQuery to get the data from the controller. The data consist of references of other Mongo object id as strings/string.

Please can someone suggest the best way to update an object in nest/mongoose. Thanks in advance

```
class UpdateProjectDto {
  @IsArray()
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString({ each: true })
  testSuits: [string];
}

class Project{
  @Prop({ type: [MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'TestSuit' })
  testSuits: TestSuit[];
}

project.service.ts
  async update(
    id: string,
    updateQuery: UpdateQuery<UpdateProjectDto>,
  ): Promise<Project> {
    return this.projectModel
      .findByIdAndUpdate(
        id,
        {
          ...updateQuery,
        },
        {
          new: true,
        },
     )
  }

**Error**
src/projects/controllers/projects.controller.ts:68:50 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'UpdateProjectDto' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UpdateQuery<ProjectDocument>'.
  Type 'UpdateProjectDto' is not assignable to type 'ReadonlyPartial<_UpdateQueryDef<DeepPartial<ProjectDocument>>>'.
    Types of property 'testSuits' are incompatible.
      Type '[string]' is not assignable to type 'DeepPartial<TestSuit>[]'.
        Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'DeepPartial<TestSuit>'.

68     return await this.projectsService.update(id, updateProjectDto);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass in the `UpdateProjectDto` directly without the `UpdateQuery`.

```
  async update(id: string, updateQuery: UpdateProjectDto): Promise<Project> {
    return this.projectModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updateQuery, {
      new: true,
    });
  }
```

That will return the updated object.